# Клиппи и Мерлин грабят банк

Tags: python, python-3.x

Клиппи и Мерлин грабят банк.

Клиппи и Мерлин решили грабить банк, который представляет собой `N`
расположенных в ряд банковских ячеек, пронумерованных последовательно числами от `1` до `N`.

С помощью своего друга Ровера, который работал в банке сторожевым псом, они добыли ключи от всех ячеек, а так же узнали, как много ценностей хранится в каждой ячейке.

Чтобы не вызывать лишних подозрений, Клиппи и Мерлин решили ограбить всего две ячейки — по одной на каждого. Также, чтобы охрана банка не почуяла неладного, они решили работать далеко друг от друга — между ними должно быть не меньше `K` банковских ячеек.

**Входные данные**

В первой строке вводятся два числа — `N ( 2 ≤ N ≤ 10^5)` и `K (0 ≤ K < N−1)` соответственно. В второй строке вводятся `N` чисел `ai(0 ≤ai≤ 10^9)` — стоимости хранимых ценностей в ячейках от `1` до `N` соответственно.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите два числа в возрастающем порядке — номера ячеек, которые нужно ограбить, чтобы суммарно украсть как можно более дорогие ценности, не вызвав при этом лишних подозрений. Если вариантов несколько выберите тот, в котором меньший номер вскрываемой ячейки был как можно ближе к единице, чтобы в экстренном случае покинуть банк как можно скорее. Если и таких вариантов несколько, выберите тот, в котором и больший номер вскрываемой ячейки был как можно меньше.

Пример:

Ввод:

```
6 2
2 4 3 1 4 4
```

Вывод:

```
2 5
```

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
ibest = 0
jbest = k + 1
j=k+1
for i in range(n):
    if j==n:
        break
    if (a[i] + a[j] > a[ibest] + a[jbest]):
        m= a[i] + a[j]
        ibest=i
        jbest=j
    j+=1
print(str(ibest+1)+' '+str(jbest+1))
```

Написал этот код, тестирующая система выдаёт ошибку(проходит 7 из 17 тестов), что нужно исправить+нужно сохранить линейную сложность O(n).
Ссылка на источник https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=13551#1

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует авторам тестирующей системы

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Почему? Интересная задача, вопрос правильно составлен - все требования соблюдены. Потому что вопрос звучит как - *"Почему тестирующая система не принимает ответ?"*, а должен звучать *"Помогите найти оптимальный алгоритм."*?

Comment: @MiniMax, краткая суть вопроса: «тестирующая система выдаёт ошибку. что нужно исправить?». такого рода вопрос (и возможные ответы на него) бесполезен для базы знаний: те, кому ответы могут быть полезны, просто не найдут их.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Название и условие задачи есть, по нему найдут. А как по другому сформулировать вопрос? Привести его к обобщённому виду типа: "Найти максимальную сумму двух элементов из левой и правой части последовательности разделённой скользящим окном"? Так вообще никто не найдёт :) Или нужно удалить упоминание тестирующей системы, оставив только условие и текущее решение? Тоже нехорошо, со ссылкой на тестирующую систему каждый может проверить своё решение. Я например, три раза переделывал, прежде, чем нашёл правильный алгоритм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение**

```
def linear(cells):
    max_a = 0
    max_a_i = 0
    max_sum = 0
    # Перебираем все возможные левые ячейки - 'a'
    for a_i, a in enumerate(cells[:-distance - 1]):
        # Находим ближайшую правую ячейку
        b_i = a_i + distance + 1
        b = cells[b_i]
        # Запоминаем левую ячейку с максимальным значением.
        if a > max_a:
            max_a = a
            max_a_i = a_i
        # По условию для текущей правой ячейки ('b') подойдёт любая
        # левая, стоящая от неё на расстоянии больше, чем 'k'.
        # Логично, что надо выбрать левую ячейку с максимальным значением.
        # Таким образом, сложив правую ячейку с максимальной левой, получаем
        # лучшую сумму для данной правой ячейки.
        if max_a + b > max_sum:
            max_sum = max_a + b
            # После проверки всех ячеек, в 'answer' будут номера
            # 'a' и 'b' с лучшей суммой
            answer = (max_a_i, b_i)

    print(answer[0] + 1, answer[1] + 1)
```

**Тестирование**

```
# Содержимое файлов с тестами
$ tail -n +1 -- input_*

==> input_1.txt <==
6 0
2 9 9 1 4 4

==> input_2.txt <==
6 1
5 7 6 8 0 0

==> input_3.txt <==
6 1
5 9 9 1 4 6

==> input_4.txt <==
10 1
1 1 4 1 1 1 3 1 3 1
```

Команда на `bash` для проверки тестов:

```
$ for f in input*; do echo "${f}"; ./source.py < "${f}"; echo; done
```

**Output**

```
input_1.txt
2 3

input_2.txt
2 4

input_3.txt
2 6

input_4.txt
3 7
```

Comment: Отлично, лишнее хранилище, как у меня, даже не понадобилось

Answer (score 2):

Приведённый код, похоже, учитывает только пары с расстоянием точно k, а нужно не меньше k

Для этого можно заполнить в**спомогательный список/массив индексом максимального  элемента в правой части списка** от каждого лемента до конца (с помощью прохода в обратном направления)

Потом идти с начала, обновляя индекс максимума в левой части списка. Результат есть максимум суммы правый максимум + левый максимум для индексов, разнесённых на k

Answer (score 0):

```
args = [int(i) for i int(input().split()]
n, k = args[0], args[1]
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

ibest = 0
jbest = k+1
imax = 0

for j in range(k+1, n):
    if a[j-k-1] > a[imax]:
        imax = j-k-1
    if (a[j] + a[imax]) > (a[jbest] + a[ibest]):
        jbest = j
        ibest = imax

print(ibest+1, jbest+1)
```

Все тесты Сириуса прошел. Если не трудно, поставьте большой палец)